# Smooth tempered distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

> We have $ f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}) $ such that
>
> $ \forall n \geq 0 \:, \exists C_n, \: \: |f^{(n)}(x)| \leq C_n (1 + |x|)^{2-n} $
>
> - Show that the distribution $ T_f $ is tempered.
> - Show that the distribution $ \widehat{T} \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}^{*}) $

I have noticed that $ |<T_f, \varphi >  | \leq C_0 (  \lVert \varphi \rVert_1 + 2C_0 \lVert x \varphi \rVert_1 + C_0 \lVert x^2 \varphi \rVert_1 \leq C_0 (  \lVert \varphi \rVert_{\infty} + 2C_0 \lVert x \varphi \rVert_{\infty} + C_0 \lVert x^2 \varphi \rVert_{\infty} \leq KN_2( \varphi)   $

And thus  $ T_f \in \mathcal{S}' $

Now I know by Fubini that $  \widehat{T_f} = T_\widehat{f} \in \mathcal{S}' $

Then perhaps $ \widehat{f} $ is well defined after all even though f is a priori not in $ L^1 $ or $ \mathcal{S} $

So to show that $ \widehat{T} \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}^{*}) $ do we need to show that $ \widehat{f} \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}^{*}) $ ? How could we proceed?  Thanks in advance.